# Dojo: Sorting a widgets store object

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to take a dojo widget object and sort its store, e.g. by alphabetical order etc?

Initially I thought about copying the store, sorting it and replacing the original with it but is there any way to do it directly on the widget object without this step?

Comment: That depends.  What widget are you referring to exactly?  Some widgets provide an API to pass options to stores' query method, like the query filter, start/count, and sort.

Comment: Why can't you set sorted store to the widget before initializing it? Do you expect the widget to sort the store himself? What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you create jsfiddle.net for that?

Comment: @KenFranqueiro it is a custom widget based off the filtering select widget

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that your widget is a (customized) FilteringSelect... try this:

```
<select 
     data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect"  
     data-dojo-props=" 
         searchAttr: 'foo',  
         labelAttr: 'bar',  
         fetchProperties:{sort:[{attribute:'baz',descending:false}]} 
     "></select>
```

With [handy dandy jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inanutshellus/oy7j6b2b/).